# Building a query programatically

Tags: mysql

I have three variables $color, $size and $category. Each oh them can be a specific value or may refer to all entries.I want to fetch all products that are $color = "red", $size = "Medium" and any category OR any color, any size and $category = "Tshirts". I can do this using if/elseif or switch and treat all cases but this means 12 cases + the one with any color, any size and any category, so 13 total cases.

Is this even possible in mySql ??

Sample query

```
SELECT
*
WHERE color = $color AND size = $size AND category = $category
```

Comment: Providing the table definition (`CREATE TABLE`), some sample rows and the query you have so far, would help. See: **[Help us help you : keys to getting good answers](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/)**

Comment: You can also use [SQLFiddle.com](http://SQLFiddle.com) and provide a link to that (table + inserted data + query) so others can test their answers faster and easier.

Comment: @ypercube I posted a sample query. The idea is that I want to know if instead of color = $color where color might be a value like 1,2,3,4 etc I want to have something like color = any . Does it makes sense?

Comment: I wonder where you got that 13 number. I'd say it's 7 for three attributes/columns (2^3-1).

Comment: @ypercube yes. you're right regarding the number, it like 1am and I didn't paid attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to keep you PHP code simple and make the SQL code more complicated, while it should be otherwise.

Example: lets say that
 - user A chooses: *"`color = 'red', size = 'Medium', category = any`"*
 - user B chooses *"`color = any, size = any, category = 'Tshirts'`"*

The conditions could be respectively as simple as:

```
-- userA
WHERE color = $color AND size = $size 
-- or the equivalent (if columns are NOT NULL):  
WHERE color = $color AND size = $size AND category = category
```

and for

```
-- userB
WHERE category = $category
-- or the equivalent (if columns are NOT NULL):
WHERE color = color  AND size = size  AND category = $category
```

I don't think it's so difficult to write PHP code that produces those conditions when a user selects some *"any"*, no matter how that *"any"* is coded in your PHP/web form.

But if you really want to pass that to MySQL, you can do something like this. Pass the *"any"* as a fixed value (say `'any'`) and use:

```
WHERE (color    = $color    OR $color    = 'any')
  AND (size     = $size     OR $size     = 'any')
  AND (category = $category OR $category = 'any')
```

Comment: I posted a sample query. The idea is that I want to know if instead of color = $color where color might be a value like 1,2,3,4 etc I want to have something like color = any . Does it makes sense?

Comment: Doesn't this query do this? It will get you all rows that have either all 3 attributes or 2 of them or only 1 (just colour or just size or just category).

Comment: Yes. But what if I need to have color = any AND size = 4 AND category = 5 . If I put OR instead of AND it will take me only the category = 5

Comment: If you want that, just use `WHERE size = 4 AND category = 5` I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I am building the query using PHP and I have three inputs and the user can select Size: Any, Color: Any, Category: Any , or Size: Medium, Color: Any, Category: Tshirts. All values beside any are numbers, I decided any option to have value="a" . So when I am building my where clause I don't want to make something like if($size == 'a' && $color == 'a' && $category == 'a") { $where = '' } elseif($size != 'a' && $color == 'a' && $category == 'a") { $where = "size = {$size}"; } etc.... Now it makes sense?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Seems that you understood what I am trying to do perfectly, but mySQL do not recognize 'any'

Comment: I used `'any'` while you had `'a'` in your code above above. Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: Anyway I found a way for what I am trying to do thanks to your answer. I didn't knew that I can do column = column in a query

Comment: I put 'any' in my code, but it seems that mysql doesn't understand 'any'

Comment: You are doing something wrong. `'any'` is a string literal and there should be no problem for mysql. Check what exactly is the sql code produced.

Comment: Yes. But who is 'any' for mySQL? I think I am not expressing myself clear enough. Too tired.